# How to copy a part of CStringArray to another CStringArray

Tags: windows, mfc

I want to copy a part of CStringArray to another CStringArray. for eq. copy is to be done from CStringArrayA[5] to CStringArrayA[9] to CStringArrayB (5 elements of CStringArrayA to CStringArrayB).

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [interface of CStringArray](http://softimage.wiki.softimage.com/sdkdocs/sicppsdk/html/classXSI_1_1CStringArray.html) it seems you don't have a significantly better option that just calling `Add` for each element in the specified range.